# How to stop opencv2 qrcode detectAndDecode from causing memory issues

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, qr-code

tl;dr: qrcode detection crashes my system and flood ram+swap and some unknown memory

**Setup:** Ubuntu 20.04 running on VirtualBox with 2gb ram, 2 processors, 10gb disk.

**Background:** I am trying to build a GUI app (using Tkinter) for reading QR-codes(qrcode.detectAndDecode) from a webcamera (openCV). The returned value from the QR code corresponds to an item in a list that is returned and placed on the screen in tkinter texboxes. I also try to show the webcam stream on the GUI.

**Current status:** Current code works for shorter times.

**Problem:** After about 30-60 seconds of running the program some kind of memory is filled and causes a crash or computer freeze. I have tried checking the *system monitor*, using *memory profiler* and *tracemalloc*. I know **what operations** in the code causes this, but not **why**. Sometimes the program crash without warning or any signs afterwards, sometimes a spike to 100% RAM and SWAP usage is seen. Please see the end for error message and system monitor screenshot.

**Code** Below you can see my code that I suspect is the problem. I have indicated with comments which part of the program that works fine, when the other parts are included then the problem starts. It seems to be problem with the QRcode detectAndDecode,, but not sure why.

I have isolated the problem code in a separate program, see below.

```
import qrcode                   
import cv2                      
from PIL import Image as PIL_Image, ImageTk as PIL_ImageTk
from tkinter import *           
import numpy as np
import threading

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,380)
cap.set(4,240)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
StreamIsOn=  False
d = cv2.QRCodeDetector()  #Activate qrcode detector object

##############################################################################################
def webcam_stream_loop():       #Function for utilizing webcamera
  while True:                       #Only one active thread
    StreamIsOn = True
    success, img = cap.read()       #read data from video feed
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert to grayscale
    WebCamCapture = PIL_Image.fromarray(img)    #convert from numpy array to PIL image
    WebCamCapture_PI = PIL_ImageTk.PhotoImage(WebCamCapture)      #convert PIL image to PhotoImage

    if not Camfeed_canvas.find_all(): #If canvas is empty, create image object
      canvas_feed = Camfeed_canvas.create_image(0,0, image=WebCamCapture_PI, anchor = "nw")
    else: #if canvas object already exist, update canvas object with new picture from video feed
      Camfeed_canvas.itemconfig(canvas_feed,image=WebCamCapture_PI)

    print(img.shape)
    print(img.size)
    print(img.dtype)
    val, points, straight_qrcode = d.detectAndDecode(img) #When i comment out this and the following 2 rows, everything works without a problem.
    if len(val) > 0: #If found QR code is different from current displayed data, and is not empty
      print(val)
#############################################################################################


root = Tk()        
root.title('Debug')  
    

############################ Startt canvas for picture display ########
Camfeed_canvas = Canvas(root, width = 340, height = 240)
Camfeed_canvas.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
#######################################################################


if StreamIsOn == False: threading.Thread(target=webcam_stream_loop, daemon = True).start() #Start thread for webcam stream

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error message I get when running the program until it crashes:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/LarpDB/LarpDB.py", line 138, in webcam_stream_loop
    val, points, straight_qrcode = d.detectAndDecode(img) #search for qr code in image
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /tmp/pip-req-build-24v3eisa/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 4624000000 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
```

[Picture of system resource usage during the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vygwv.png)

**Best Regards**

Comment: please work to present a [mre]. that means *complete, runnable* code, but strip out everything that isn't *required* to cause the issue. -- also debug the code, meaning to `print()` `img`'s properties before every `detectAndDecode` call (properties such as, its `.shape`)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have updated my initial post with a program where this problem code is isolated. It should run as it is if all the dependencies are installed.

Comment: you keep calling `create_image` without cleaning the old picture up. did you watch that codemy youtube tutorial series where he bungles through it all and never explains anything in depth?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Lol, yes. Codemy is the source for this. My thinking with the if statement was to only do create_Image once if there was no image in Camfeed_canvas alread, to avoid this problem? Shoud not this: `if not Camfeed_canvas.find_all(): `return `true` if the canvas has no objects?

Comment: the tkinter image objects go invisible when their underlying image object is garbage collected, but they're probably still there (invisible). that would be my first guess as to where the memory goes. -- my second quess would be that insane allocation of 4 GB in the QR API. -- tbh I don't know where the memory leak is or why it happens, or where exactly to start looking. your code is generally too much to even guess. usual approach is to start from scratch and watch what code is required to cause it, and then remove things again, until the problem stops again.

Comment: actually, yes, the QR stuff looks suspicious. it shouldn't attempt to allocate "4624000000 bytes" for any reason really, unless you give it strange inputs. look at the inputs. strive to cause this error as quickly as possible. -- state your version of OpenCV. also see what other interesting facts `cv.getBuildInformation()` can tell you

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I solved it, maybe a bit ugly and only treating the symptom but it works, by doing a try and except statement, which just throws away the bad frame. It seems to be working.

Comment: I'm glad this issue can be worked around. if you manage to catch such a picture that causes this, and causes this reproducibly, I'm sure the OpenCV developers would love to receive that test case.